# The version of Metro bundled with JavaSE?

Tags: java, jax-ws, java-metro-framework

Java SE 6 and later come bundled with Metro. Surprisingly, a *Java ver x -> Metro ver y* list is nowhere to be found.

How can I find out what version of Metro is bundled with my JVM? Either by inspecting the VM at runtime or by checking a file from the installed JVM.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

JDK 6 comes bundled with JAX-WS RI. GlassFish Metro is a web services stack that includes JAX-WS RI among other components like JAXB RI or StAX, but it's a separate project.
So you would have to download the Metro jars if you want to use it.

JDK 6 started including JAX-WS RI 2.0 and since update 4 it includes JAX-WS RI 2.1.

You can find the JAX-WS RI version your JDK is using with the wsimport command: `wsimport -version`.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out `wsimport -version`! As you see in my answer, `JavaSE` itself indicates the `RI`. And other places on the net also claim that a reference is included in JavaSE itself. Otoh, I had to download and include [Metro - (somewhat confusingly offered at jax-ws.java.net)](https://jax-ws.java.net) on my `Tomcat 7`, running on `Java 7`, to get it to work. It's rather confusing which is which.

Comment: Yes you are right Eugene, I should have said JAX-WS RI instead, so I edited my answer with your info, thanks. As you say, there's always a lot of confusion with all the nomenclature refering to this topic but the bottom line is that JAX-WS is a Java Specification Request ([JSR 224](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=224)) and JAX-WS RI is the reference implementation of this specification, developed by Glassfish too.

Answer (score 3):

Using `wsimport -version` as per David Lizárraga's answer, for various `JavaSE 1.7.0` builds I triedon Windows and Linux, I get

```
JAX-WS RI 2.2.4-b01
```

This, and David's answer, yield the following table.

```
 JavaSE   JAX-WS RI
--------+----------
      6        2.1  
      7      2.2.4
```